# Can I have custom GarageBand track icons?

Tags: garageband

Is it possible to manually define a custom icon on track in GarageBand? Having something like a usericon I see on web sites makes knowing whose track I'm editing much easier than having to read relatively small text with the person's name on it.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this eHow video.](http://www.ehow.com/video_4955196_changing-icons-garageband.html) I couldn't get it to load on my computer (it's slow because I'm rendering video in FCE). I also found [this article.](http://garageband.maccreate.com/2010/11/15/changing-instrument-icons-in-garageband-11/) I'm not sure if that'll help or not.

According to [this article:](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=60587)

> There is some code somewhere in GarageBand that allows you to expand the number of icons you can use. But dog if I know where it is. There are two things you can do, either spring for a JamPack and let it automatically expand your icons, or replace ugly or stupid icons (there are plenty) with the ones you want.
>
> As to the "How to", go to the link below and download my custom icons and directions to accomplish this.
> http://garritan.com/GPO-GarageBandPage.html
> Here is a direct link...
> http://garritan.com/support/GB_Icon_Set.zip
>
> To make your own icons, just open one of the triads in Photoshop and then save as a tif file.

As Wheat noted below, the links are dead, but you can download the icon set [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20061217081251/http://garritan.com/support/GB_Icon_Set.zip) (go Wayback Machine!)
The other link is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20081202133416/http://garritan.com/GPO-GarageBandPage.html) on Wayback Machine.

Comment: daviesgeek, those are dead links in your "According to this article" section.

Comment: @Wheat Fixed the links.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not easy.  Its a bit of a hack.

Details are in [this](http://www.bulletsandbones.com/GB/FAQPages/CreateIcons.html) article.

Comment: I was hoping to have an answer other than this. I've come across this before, but I can't believe it's the best answer, predominately because of things like the feature I mention in [my other GarageBand/iChat question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14114/application-bridge-for-ichat-audio-video-channels).